# EventFilter in Context Menu in JavaFx

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

My javafx application has graphs made of nodes and edges. The Edges are implemented using 'Line' shape. There is a 'ContentMenu' used on edges when the user right clicks on it. There is another ContextMenu used with the main UI canvas on which the graph is constructed.

The issue is that the canvas context menu is overriding the edge contextmenu. Whenever a user right clicks an edge, its contextmenu appears and then quickly disappears to show the canvas contextmenu.

I've written an EventFilter on right click MOUSE_RELEASED of the edges to consume the mouse event, but this doesnt solve the issue either.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] and include it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You chose wrong event. You need to consume `ContextMenuEvent` to suppress Context Menu. See next code

```
    node.addEventFilter(ContextMenuEvent.ANY, new EventHandler<Event>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Event event) {
            event.consume();
        }
    });
```

Comment: unfortunately the canvas contextmenu still overrides the edge contextmenu once the key is released.

Comment: @Ulkurz in this case we really need to see how do you assign filters and handers to find a problem. Please, try to prepare https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: thanks, I finally was able to figure it out. :)